# Delegate variables Vs. Core Data

Tags: ios, variables, core-data, delegates

I wonder when I should use Core Data and when I just should keep it easy and use delegate variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate is a design pattern, CoreData a persistence framework. You are comparing things, that are not compare-able.

**Edit**

#### Delegate:

A delegate is an "entry point" where an objects allows you to define some custom action.
It is similair to callbacks in some language or interface in Java.
Technically a delegate is just a pointer to an object that conforms to a defined [protocol](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007594-CH1-SW1)

> Delegation is a simple and powerful
>   pattern in which one object in a
>   program acts on behalf of, or in
>   coordination with, another object. The
>   delegating object keeps a reference to
>   the other object—the delegate—and at
>   the appropriate time sends a message
>   to it. The message informs the
>   delegate of an event that the
>   delegating object is about to handle
>   or has just handled. The delegate may
>   respond to the message by updating the
>   appearance or state of itself or other
>   objects in the application, and in
>   some cases it can return a value that
>   affects how an impending event is
>   handled. The main value of delegation
>   is that it allows you to easily
>   customize the behavior of several
>   objects in one central object.

#### CoreData

[CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GettingStartedWithCoreData/index.html) is a Framework for organizing persistence data.

> In simplest terms, Core Data is an
>   object graph that can be persisted to
>   Disk. [...] Core Data can do a lot
>   more for us. It serves as the entire
>   model layer for us. It is not just the
>   persistence on disk, but it is also
>   all the objects in memory that we
>   normally consider to be data objects.
>
> —Marcus Zarra, Core Data

Comment: When writing an app you can use the delegate for storing global variables. You can also use CoreData to store data?